# How to print values of class fields along with the parent ones?

Tags: java

This is my child class. i want to print values of fields with toString method. can any one plz help me how i print child class fields as well parent class fields

```
public class Student extends StudentAddress {

    private String studentName;
    private String courseName;


    public Student(
            String address1,
            String address2,
            int mob,
            String studentName,
            String courseName) {
        super(address1, address2, mob);
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void display(Student s){
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("add1","add2",122,"Abc","MMC");
        System.out.println(student);
        student.display(student);
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "studentName='" + studentName + '\'' +
                ", courseName='" + courseName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is parent class.

```
public class StudentAddress {

    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private int mob;

    public StudentAddress(String address1, String address2, int mob) {
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.mob = mob;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentAddress{" +
                "address1='" + address1 + '\'' +
                ", address2='" + address2 + '\'' +
                ", mob=" + mob +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I want print all the 5 fields values;

Comment: call `super.toString()` from sub class' s `toString()`. btw `Student extends StudentAddress` makes no sense

Comment: i just want to call student and print all the fields values

Comment: I understand that this is for demo purpose only, but you should consider naming the classes differently. It does not make sense for a something that models a _Student_ to specialize (extend) something that models an _Address_.

Answer (score 1):

in `Student`, use `super.toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    return "Student{" +
            "studentName='" + studentName + '\'' +
            ", courseName='" + courseName + '\'' +
            '}'+super.toString();
}
```

of course i don't know how you want to format the output , so make necessary changes as needed.